# Conditional check inside navigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use a StackNavigator in my app. If the device is an iPhone X, I want to set a custom navigation header height. Setting a header hight worked perfectly with this code

```
User: {
          screen: UserContainer,
          navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.title,
            headerStyle: {height: 100}
          })
        }
```

I have a function called isIphoneX() that returns true if the device is an iphone X. How can I use this function to set the header custom value only on iPhone X and keep the default value on the other devices? Something like

```
User: {
          screen: UserContainer,
          navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.title,
            if(isIphoneX()){  // this dose not work
            headerStyle: {height: 100}
            }
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't just put IF Statment into the Object literal.The thing could help you is called ternary operator - assuming `isIphoneX()` returns Boolean.

```
User: {
  screen: UserContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title,
    headerStyle: isIphoneX() ? { height: 100 } : {}
  })
}
```